# Objective-c xml-parsing

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have `xmlNode *node` that contains: `<div class="text">1<br>2,3</div>` If i use **first code** i get:`<div class="text"><br></div>` and if i use **second code** i get:`null`. Maybe someone know how i can get numbers?

**First code**

```
xmlBufferPtr buffer = xmlBufferCreateSize(1000);
xmlOutputBufferPtr buf = xmlOutputBufferCreateBuffer(buffer, NULL);

htmlNodeDumpOutput(buf, node->doc, node, (const char*)node->doc->encoding);

xmlOutputBufferFlush(buf);

NSString * string = nil;

if (buffer->content) {
    string = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:(const void *)xmlBufferContent(buffer) length:xmlBufferLength(buffer) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

xmlOutputBufferClose(buf);
xmlBufferFree(buffer);

return string;
```

**Second code**

```
void * contents = xmlNodeGetContent(node);
if (contents)
{
    NSString * string = [NSString stringWithCString:contents encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    xmlFree(contents);
    return string;
}
```

Comment: can you paste the xml data in the question ?

Comment: @Esha the `node` consists of only one line: <div class="text">1<br>2,3</div>